# What do we do with questions which don't have enough info?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Sometimes there are questions which don't quite have enough information to be certain what the full situation is.

For example:

- [Dynamic Paint Brush Erase doesn't work in Render Output](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5484/599)
- [Cycles: No transparency in 3D View in material viewport shading mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10982/cycles-no-transparency-in-3d-view-in-material-viewport-shading-mode)

In these questions, it's pretty clear what the OP is asking, but the full story needed to precisely solve the issue is not as obvious (to me, at least..). By "full story", I mean knowing if specific settings are enabled/disabled, the state of various caches, what kind of hardware is used, etc. All the variables likely to affect the features the OP is using.

When the OP doesn't respond to requests for clarification, what do we do with these?

Should we close them? If so, what should the close reason say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it on hold as "unclear what you're asking" and leave a comment requesting more information. If no information is added after 5 days, the question is closed.